# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser at org.altbeacon.beacon

Tags: ads, altbeacon, bluetoothadapter

Getting error on Asus, Samsung tablets having OS version 4.4.2
Android Beacon Library version.

Getting below Issue.

I tried updating the library, handling the crash but still able to see below error:-

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser at
>   org.altbeacon.beacon.g.(Unknown Source) at
>   com.mangomirror.app.activity.a.b(Unknown Source) at
>   com.mangomirror.app.activity.HomeActivity$2.a(Unknown Source) at
>   d.g$a$1$1.run(Unknown Source) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Below is my Code:-

```
public void broadcastAsBeacon(int major, int minor) {
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
.setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
.setId2(String.valueOf(major))
.setId3(String.valueOf(minor))
.setManufacturer(0x004C)
.setTxPower(txPower)
.setRssi(-89)
.setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l}))
.build();

    BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");//
    try {
        beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(this, beaconParser);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(e));
    }

    if (beaconTransmitter!=null) {
        beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                Log.e("Class", "Advertisement start failed with code: " + errorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                Log.i("class", "Advertisement start succeeded." + settingsInEffect.getTxPowerLevel());
                Log.i("class", "Advertisement start succeeded." + settingsInEffect);
            }
        });
    }
}

private boolean isBleEnabled() {
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
    } else {
        if (bluetoothAdapter!=null) {
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLE);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transmission is only supported on Android 5.0+.  Per the library [docs](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter.html), you must check to see if transmission is supported first by calling

```
int result = BeaconTransmitter.checkTransmissionSupported(context);
```

If the device supports transmission, the method returns BeaconTransmitter.SUPPORTED. It may also return:

```
NOT_SUPPORTED_MIN_SDK
NOT_SUPPORTED_BLE
NOT_SUPPORTED_MULTIPLE_ADVERTISEMENTS (deprecated)
NOT_SUPPORTED_CANNOT_GET_ADVERTISER_MULTIPLE_ADVERTISEMENTS
NOT_SUPPORTED_CANNOT_GET_ADVERTISER
```